# Random crash with skyrim wined on Linux with an AMD graphic card

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, linux

For the Last 6 months, I encountered random crash playing skyrim on my Linux stack. The computer crashed with a random play time: from a minute to rarely an hour.

I ve tried everything: testing memory with memtest, monitoring cpu and cgu temp, everything is under 50C degrees in full charge.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution i found to solve these crashes / freezes :

it appears it is Mesa drivers related, according to an article on [phoronics](http://phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=9-Year-Mesa-Bug-RadeonSI) and this particular [issue](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93649)

Seems like, beyond a Team Fortress 2 issue, it occurs in many other titles using openGL on AMD graphic cards.

**On Ubuntu :**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```